# the if else if statement not working the way I thought would have worked

Tags: javascript

I was making a winner checking system where, if I get 2 same numbers from a die than the innerHTML of the result should change from 'result' to 'you win!', if I didn't get same numbers, then the innerHTML of the 'p' should keep showing 'keep trying' but the if else if statement I was working with didn't give me the output I needed and instead of showing 'You win' or 'keep trying' in different cases, it keeps showing 'you win' when clearly my both numbers don't match with each other.

here's the js code:

```
var dice1 = document.getElementById('you');
var dice2 = document.getElementById('cpu');
var result = document.getElementById('rslt');
var button = document.getElementById('btn');

// Button Interaction

function randomNumbers() {
  document.getElementById('you').innerHTML = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6);
  document.getElementById('cpu').innerHTML = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6);
}

// Result

function checkWin() {
  if (you.innerHTML == cpu.innerHTML) {
    return rslt.innerHTML = "You Win!";

  } else if (you.innerHTML != cpu.innerHTML) {
    return rslt.innerHTML = "Keep on trying!";

  } else {

    return rslt.innerHTML = "Keep on trying!";
  }
}

checkWin();
```

Please tell me what mistake I did. I'm a novice in programming with javascript, so please dont bully me.

Thank you if you read this far!

Comment: You've got a function for randomNumbers but where is this initiated? Use console.log(values) and open the inspect window of your browsers development tools and go to "Console". That will tell you what the values of you.innerHTML and cpu.innerHTML are so you can see if they are equal or not

Comment: Please take all those backticks out of your code and just use the button in the editor to format.

Comment: the numbers are initiated into the webpage with the help of the html I created

Answer (score 0):

Wrap into variables and then try to use if else or as you already did with dice1 and dice2

```
  var you = document.getElementById('you').innerHTML = Math.floor(Math.random()*6);
  var cpu = document.getElementById('cpu').innerHTML = Math.floor(Math.random()*6);

if(you == cpu)
```

Answer (score 0):

You should call `checkwin()` when you button is pressed

Try this code

```
  var dice1 = document.getElementById('you');

    var dice2 = document.getElementById('cpu');

    var result = document.getElementById('rslt');

    var button = document.getElementById('btn');

    // Button Interaction

    function randomNumbers(){

    document.getElementById('you').innerHTML = Math.floor(Math.random()*6);
    document.getElementById('cpu').innerHTML = Math.floor(Math.random()*6);
    checkWin();
    }

    // Result

    function checkWin(){

    if(you.innerHTML == cpu.innerHTML)

    { return rslt.innerHTML = "You Win!";

    } else if (you.innerHTML != cpu.innerHTML)

    { return rslt.innerHTML = "Keep on trying!";

    } else {

        return rslt.innerHTML = "Keep on trying!";
    }

    }
```

Comment: it worked!!! thanks alot mate! I didn't even realise I had to do that!